# Where does pyspark-shell in PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS come from?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

While I was reading a notebook in jupyter that does some pyspark job, encountered a code line saying

`os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = f'--name "test submit" --master yarn --deploy-mode client pyspark-shell'`

I mostly understand this line but not the last argumnet `pyaprk-shell`. So I googled `PYSPARK_SUMIT_ARGS` to read full spec about this environment variable. Problem is that I couldn't find the documentation about it. All research results was saying to use it but not why and what it actually does. Couldn't find about it in the official documentation too.

I can assume it says to use pyspark(Python), not spark(R), to process my job, yet I want to read exactly how and what it does. So where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the [code for Spark-Submit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala).  Look for PYSPARK_SHELL it's basically used to select what java class to use to run your code.